# Can't insert keyframe in graph editor

Tags: interface, keyframes

When I go to insert a keyframe in the graph editor using the <kbd>I</kbd> keyboard shortcut, or right-clicking and choosing **insert keyframe** from the menu, I get the context menu letting me choose all channels, only selected etc., but then nothing happens. I'm in pose mode, and the bone I want to add the keyframe for is selected.

[image]

[Here is a simple scene](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EpwPZV2qM4plGFUd-at6V3g3buoD3d7z/view?usp=sharing) with just the cube animated. If I select a channel in the graph editor I see this same behaviour.

Comment: maybe the track is locked?

Comment: no, all of the channels on the bone are unlocked.

Comment: maybe share a part of your file so that we can test?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, I added a link to a simple file.

Comment: it works here so I have no idea why it doesn't for you  :/  https://zupimages.net/up/20/38/ycpf.gif

Comment: Damn, I was hoping it wasn't going to be like that.

Comment: Works for me in 2.9